# Problems with the pong game developed in canvas javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a pong game with a square ball, which I want to transform into a round one. However, when I attempt to do that I get a line that follows my pong ball. Could someone help me solve this?

[Screenshot with square ball](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h22LS.png)

[Screenshot with round ball](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OZ8B.png)

**Code:**

```
        // Draw the Ball
        if (Pong._turnDelayIsOver.call(this)) {
            ///// Square code
            /*this.context.fillRect(
                this.ball.x,
                this.ball.y,
                this.ball.width,
                this.ball.height
            );*/

            ////round code
            this.context.arc(this.ball.x, this.ball.y, this.ball.width, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
            this.context.stroke();
            this.context.fill();
        }

        // Draw the net (Line in the middle)
        this.context.beginPath();
        this.context.setLineDash([7, 15]);
        this.context.moveTo((this.canvas.width / 2), this.canvas.height - 140);
        this.context.lineTo((this.canvas.width / 2), 140);
        this.context.lineWidth = 10;
        this.context.strokeStyle = '#ffffff';
        this.context.stroke();
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

EDIT: "The correct answer is that the OP should have added `ctx.beginPath()` above the call `ctx.arc`". Thanks @Blindman67 for pointing this out.

(Original answer for reference: You are most likely missing a call to `this.context.closePath()` before you start drawing the second shape (otherwise the ball and the net are being drawn with the same shape, which results in the problem you have in the second picture)
)

Cheers!

Comment: Thank God that you took the time to help me, that worked perfectly

Comment: Sorry -1 as answer is very wrong and it is just luck that close path made the artifact go away. `closePath()` adds a line segment, It does not clear the current path. it is not the opposite of `beginPath` (which clears the current path) ,  The ball and net is still being rendered twice, but without the connecting line segment. The correct answer is that the OP should have added `ctx.beginPath()` above the call `ctx.arc`.

Comment: My bad @Blindman67. I updated the answer in order to avoid keeping incorrect information on the site.